# add class for all children

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have some html,.. for example:

```
<div id='mainDiv'>
   <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
   </ul>
   <div><span>text</span></div>
   <div><span>another text</span></div>
   <p>lalala</p>
</div>
```

How I can to foreach all childs from `mainDiv` and add some `data-attr` in every children

```
HtmlNode mainDiv = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='mainDiv']");
```

Comment: Direct children or all descendants?

Comment: It allways helps if you'd add the desired output too...

Comment: for direct children do mainDiv.SelectNodes("./*") iterate over them and add your attribute

Comment: for all descendants its ".//*" if i'm not mistaken

Comment: this helps: http://xpath.alephzarro.com/content/cheatsheet.html

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger all childrens and all descendants?

Comment: only ul / div / div /p or all descendants... including li li li span span...

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger for all including li, span, p

Comment: check my answer... i added both =)

Comment: theres also the possibility that the element has allready a class... you could replace it like i did or concaternate the existing with the new

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger in your answer you add attribute class with value data-attr, but my request it was to add attribute data-attr for example <div data-attr='something'> and this data-attr='something' adding for every descendants,.. div,p,span,li,ul all that exists

Comment: Your question said class... but just exchange class with data-attr and data-attr with whatever you need to and you are golden?

Comment: No need to say thank you, but you are welcome =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative just iterate over the children

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.Load("Demo.html");

        HtmlNode mainDiv = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='mainDiv']");

        foreach (var child in mainDiv.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (child.Attributes.Any(att=> att.Name == "class"))
            {
                child.Attributes["class"].Value = "data-attr";
            }
            else
            {
                child.Attributes.Add("class", "data-attr");
            }
        }

        document.Save("Demo.html");
    }
}
```

Or all descendants:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.Load("Demo.html");

        HtmlNode mainDiv = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='mainDiv']");

        foreach (var child in mainDiv.Descendants())
        {
            if (child.Attributes.Any(att=> att.Name == "class"))
            {
                child.Attributes["class"].Value = "data-attr";
            }
            else
            {
                child.Attributes.Add("class", "data-attr");
            }
        }

        document.Save("Demo.html");
    }
}
```